# Why can't new feeds be posted inline?

Tags: support, chat, feed

I've prepared a new feed to alert users of new feeds. The feed URL is:

> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/feeds/featured

...and the [feeds page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge?tab=feeds) seems to confirm the feed has been parsed correctly, as the feed title appears in the feeds list as opposed to its url.

Yet, [the associated feed user never spoke](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=http&user=-68&room=35). Why is that?

---

Update: I changed two feeds ([1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=modern-warfare-3&sort=newest), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=skyrim&sort=newest)) that worked just fine in the uselessly annoying popup to inline, and they've stopped posting since. Move them back to popup and they resume posting. It's not even something about the new users, as new feeds also can't post inline even by the Stack Exchange user.

Did we hit some kind of silent limit?

Comment: Before you wonder - [yes, searching like that does work](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=http&user=-30&room=35)

Comment: The Feeds union went on strike because there were no longer enough peanuts to go around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid flooding, the same post won't be posted as a message to the same room twice. Since The Bridge already has a [feed that posts *all* new questions from Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/feeds), any question will already have been posted to the room by the time it gets featured.

Comment: Ooooooh, I see. I guess that makes sense.